# Facebook Live Stream crash

Tags: streaming, live, obs

I am using OBS to stream on facebook.
I could connect to facebook with OBS and see preview at facebook (audio and video is streaming in preview mode at facebook). When I go live it stop working.

What can be the issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First try to identify the error with their ["OBS Log Analyzer"](https://obsproject.com/analyzer) to check for configuration problems, incorrect settings, network issues and many other diagnostics.

After that you should be able to start a ["OBS Live Chat"](https://obsproject.com/chat). A copy of your OBS log file will likely be very useful.

In the meanwhile you can always look through their FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Reason why I could not login was that I was in rights setting.
I had admin right to the facebook fun page but as employee of business facebook account. I had to same admin rights but not as employee.